# laravel notification using slack does not format correctly

Tags: php, laravel

Having issues trying to format the from & image etc..

It never seems to change.. any advice?

```
public function toSlack($notifiable)
{

    $user = \App\User::find($this->order->user_id);
    return (new SlackMessage)
            // ->from('HQ')
            // ->image('https://laravel.com/favicon.png')
            // ->to('#notifications')
            ->content('$'.$this->order->unit_amount.' '.$user->name);
}
```

Comment: you did remove the comments(slashes) right?

Comment: Pls provide an example of what exatctly is not working. Can you add a screenshot of the message and describe how you want it to be?